# Why do you see the size of the image loaded(in libgdx) in memory takes up more of your own photos

Tags: image, memory, bitmap, libgdx

I do not photograph with the size of 2048 x 2048 and the size of 437kb. But when it loads libgdx my memory rises sharply(4mb). It seems that in general opengl the file type&compress is not due and only to see the Bitmap in memory.

The problem is that many images are in Android at a time when the number of asset loading program exits without error.

My game is strategic, including wallpaper and buildings as well as lots of character. At the same time according to need them at the scene, there is no possibility of cross loading. (Games like clash of clans).

Now the question is how big I have a lot and I load the image into memory to play on Android phones with low ram applicable.

Comment: You sure it exits without error? 4MB should be no problem at all. Have you tried splitting up your `2048x2048` in `4 x 1024x1024`? Sorry, because of your english I have to ask, are you loading 2048 textures or not? 2048 might be too much for mobile, yet I would expect an error if that would crash it. And 2048x2048 would be 4370kB rather then 437kB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because the OpenGL stores images in uncompressed picture formats. The memory can be commpressed using S3TC_DXT texture compression algоrithms. To enable it you just must specify texture compression algorithm in your `glTexImage2D` call.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE2D, 0, GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT, width, height, 0, externalFormat, GL_BYTE);
```

You can also check if texture is compressed calling:

```
int iFlag;
glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_COMPRESSED, &iFlag);
```

Or load already compressed DDS textures by calling:

```
void glCompressedTexImage2D(GLenum target, GLint level, GLenum internalFormat,
                        GLsizei width, GLsizei height,
                        GLint border, GLsizei imageSize, void *data);
```

---

**Some more information on S3 Texture Compress (S3TC) is provided below (taken from https://www.opengl.org/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression):**

S3TC is a technique for compressing images for use as textures. Standard image compression techniques like JPEG and PNG can achieve greater compression ratios than S3TC. However, S3TC is designed to be implemented in high-performance hardware. JPEG and PNG decompress images all-at-once, while S3TC allows specific sections of the image to be decompressed independently.

S3TC is a block-based format. The image is broken up into 4x4 blocks. For non-power-of-two images that aren't a multiple of 4 in size, the other colors of the 4x4 block are taken to be black. Each 4x4 block is independent of any other, so it can be decompressed independently.

There are 3 forms of S3TC accepted by OpenGL. These forms are named after the old Direct3D names for these formats: DXT1, DXT3 and DXT5.

**DXT1 Format**

A DXT1-compressed image is an RGB image format. As such, the alpha of any color is assumed to be 1. Each 4x4 block takes up 64-bits of data, so compared to a 24-bit RGB format, it provides 6:1 compression. You can get a DXT1 image by using the `GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT` as the internal format of the image.

Each 4x4 block stores color data as follows. There are 2 16-bit color values, color0 followed by color1. Following this is a 32-bit unsigned integer containing values that describe how the two colors are combined to determine the color for a given pixel.

The 2 16-bit color values are stored in little-endian format, so the low byte of the 16-bit color comes first in each case. The color values are stored in RGB order (from high bit to low bit) in `5_6_5` bits.

The 32-bit unsigned integer is also stored in little-endian format. Every 2 bits of the integer represent a pixel; the 2 bits are a code that defines how to combine color0 and color1 to produce the color of that pixel. In order from highest bit to lowest bit (after the little-endian conversion), the pixels are stored in row-major order. Every 8 bits, 4 2-bit codes, is a single row of the image.

Here is a diagram of the setup:

```
63       55       47       39       31       23       15       7        0
| c0-low | c0-hi  | c1-low | c1-hi  | codes0 | codes1 | codes2 | codes3 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

c0-low​ is the low byte of the 16-bit color 0; similarly, c0-hi​ is the high byte of color 0. To reconstitute color 0, simply do this: `((bytes[1] << 8) + bytes[0])​`, where bytes​ is the an array containing the above sequence of bytes. Color 1 would come from `((bytes[3] << 8) + bytes[2])​`.

Similarly, the codes​ are the bytes that make up the 32-bit integer bitcodes. They have to be rebuilt in reverse order, so codes3​ is the left-most byte.

Once rebuilt into their proper order, you can get the individual 2-bit values like this. The The pixel values are in cXY​ form, where Y goes bottom to top as is standard for OpenGL:

```
31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
 | c00 | c10 | c20 | c30 | c01 | c11 | c21 | c31 | c02 | c12 | c22 | c32 | c03 | c13 | c23 | c33 
 |       codes3          |       codes2          |       codes1          |       codes0
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The interpretation of the 2-bit values depends on how color0 and color1 compare to each other. If the integer value of color0 is greater than color1, then the 2-bit values mean something different than if color0 is less than or equal to color1. The meaning of the 2-bit values is as follows:

```
code | color0 > color1         | color0 <= color1 
----------------------------------------------------
0    | color0                  | color0  
1    | color1                  | color1  
2    | (2*color0 + color1) / 3 | (color0 + color1) / 2  
3    | (color0 + 2*color1) / 3 | Black
```

The arithmetic operations are done per-component, not on the integer value of the colors. And the value "Black" is simply R=G=B=0.

**DXT1 with 1-bit Alpha**

There is a form of DXT1 available that provides a simple on/off alpha value. This format therefore uses an RGBA base format. To get this format, use the `GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT1_EXT` internal format.

The format of the data is identical to the above case, which is why this is still DXT1 compression. The interpretation differs slightly. You always get an alpha value of 1 unless the pixel uses the code for Black in the above table. In that case, you get an alpha value of 0.

Note that this means that the RGB colors will also be 0 on any pixel with a 0 alpha. This also means that bilinear filtering between neighboring texels will result in colors combined with black. If you are using premultipled alpha blending, this is what you want. If you aren't, then it almost certainly is not what you want.

When using OpenGL to compress a texture, the GL implementation will assume any pixel with an alpha value < 0.5 should have an alpha of 0. This is another reason to manually compress images.

**DXT3 Format**

The DXT3 format is an RGBA format. Each 4x4 block takes up 128 bits of data. Thus, compared to a 32-bit RGBA texture, it offers 4:1 compression. You can get this with the `GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT3_EXT` internal format.

Each block of 128 bits is broken into 2 64-bit chunks. The second chunk contains the color information, compressed almost as in the DXT1 case; the difference being that color0 is always assumed to be less than color1 in terms of determining how to use the codes to extract the color value. The first chunk contains the alpha information.

The alpha 64-bit chunk is stored as a little-endian 64-bit unsigned integer. The alpha values are stored as 4-bit-per-pixel alpha values. The alpha values are stored in row-major order, from the highest bit of the 64-bit unsigned integer.

**DXT5 Format**

The DXT5 format is an alternate RGBA format. As in the DXT3 case, each 4x4 block takes up 128 bits. So it provides the same 4:1 compression as in the DXT3 case. You can get this with the `GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT5_EXT` format.

Just as for the DXT3 format, there are two 64-bit chunks of data per block: an RGB chunk compressed as for DXT1 (with the same caveat as for DXT3), and an alpha chunk. Again the second chunk is the color chunk; the first is the alpha.

Where DXT3 and DXT5 differ is how the alpha chunk is compressed. DXT5 compresses the alpha using a compression scheme similar to DXT1.

The alpha data is stored as 2 8-bit alpha values, alpha0 and alpha1, followed by a 48-bit unsigned integer that describes how to combine these two reference alpha values to achieve the final alpha value. The 48-bit integer is also stored in little-endian order.

The 48-bit unsigned integer contains 3-bit codes that describe how to compute the final alpha value. These codes are stored in the identical order as the codes in DXT1; they simply are 3 bits in size rather than 2.

Just as in the DXT1 case, the codes have different meanings depending on how alpha0 and alpha1 compare to one another. Here is the table of codes and computations:

```
code | alpha0 > alpha1        | alpha0 <= alpha1 
---------------------------------------------
0    |alpha0                  | alpha0  
1    |alpha1                  | alpha1
2    |(6*alpha0 + 1*alpha1)/7 | (4*alpha0 + 1*alpha1)/5  
3    |(5*alpha0 + 2*alpha1)/7 | (3*alpha0 + 2*alpha1)/5  
4    |(4*alpha0 + 3*alpha1)/7 | (2*alpha0 + 3*alpha1)/5  
5    |(3*alpha0 + 4*alpha1)/7 | (1*alpha0 + 4*alpha1)/5  
6    |(2*alpha0 + 5*alpha1)/7 | 0.0  
7    |(1*alpha0 + 6*alpha1)/7 | 1.0
```

More info at [S3 Texture Compression](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression)

There are also more modern texture compression algorithms

For OpenGL 4.2 OpenGL-ES 3.0 **[Ericsson Texture Compression](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/ES3_compatibility.txt)** (ETC):

```
GL_COMPRESSED_RGB8_ETC2
GL_COMPRESSED_SRGB8_ETC2
GL_COMPRESSED_RGB8_PUNCHTHROUGH_ALPHA1_ETC2
GL_COMPRESSED_SRGB8_PUNCHTHROUGH_ALPHA1_ETC2
GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA8_ETC2_EAC
GL_COMPRESSED_SRGB8_ALPHA8_ETC2_EAC
GL_COMPRESSED_R11_EAC
GL_COMPRESSED_SIGNED_R11_EAC
GL_COMPRESSED_RG11_EAC
GL_COMPRESSED_SIGNED_RG11_EAC
```

And **[Adaptive Scalable Texture Compression](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/KHR/texture_compression_astc_hdr.txt)**.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing. There is a big difference between saying "see ___ for more information", and "all of this is taken from ____"

Comment: @Matt: Thank you for guidance.